# new to CRM, how to get CRM environment for learning and work around

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I m a .net developer and new to CRM. Unfortunately at my work we don't have CRM. I m intrested in learning CRM but not sure how I can get CRM environment for practice and learning.

Please guide should I go for CRM 2015 ? Should it be installed on labtop or Azure or is there a way I can pay and use some environment already avilable for learners ?

Kindly also help is there a licence for learners or which licence or installation is recommended for me.

Thank you so much for your precious time and valuable guidance.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this link lasts, but you can sign up for a free CRM Online trial that is CRM 2015. It will give you a 30-day trial that you may extend through the admin portal. You will walk through setting up an account, and Microsoft will automatically spin the environment up for you. See the link below.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx